# From where did he get 2 scissors and 4 papers?

Tags: kaiji

In episode 5 of Kaiji, Kaiji plays scissors against Kitami.

Later in the same episode, we find out he has 2 scissors and 4 papers other than 30 rocks. Where did he get these?

Comment: If I remember correctly, he had them because some people with 3 stars (or more) gave papers and scissors along with the stones so that they no longer had any cards and could climb upstairs.

Comment: It's been 7 years since I've seen Kaiji season 1. What exactly do you mean to ask? I mean I recall Kaiji had some cards besides the 30 rocks. What about the 2 scissors and 4 papers doesn't make sense? I guess we could figure it out if we trace his exact card inventory from the beginning. One way this question could make sense if you noticed that Kaiji seemed to have 4 scissors and 4 papers immediately prior to playing against Kitami and then having 2 scissors and 4 papers immediately after. Then we'd wonder where the other scissors went.

Answer (score 1):

After being tasked with collecting as many rocks as possible, and then splitting up, the group mentality was that while collecting scissors and paper was not the goal, there was nothing wrong with it. I can't remember whether or not Alix's answer is specifically how it happened but it may very well have been. I can however remember that it was insinuated that they were collected after they split during one (or multiple) trades in their mission to collect rock cards. There did not need to be a specific time or reason they got those cards as the writers covered their bases in the montage of trading/collecting cards.